# Anchor Tag broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain why my anchor tag is broken:
http://jsfiddle.net/7k9s1pg7/7/embedded/result/#michaelschumacher

In this example, the page should anchor down to 'Michael Schumacher'. However, it doesn't. Why is this?

**HTML:**

```
<dl class="accordion">

<dt><a href="" class="container heading">Soccer</a></dt>
<dd id="soccer">
  <div id="manutd">

    <p>Man Utd</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>  

  <div id="celtic">

    <p>Celtic</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</dd>

<dt><a href="" class="container heading">Formula 1</a></dt>
<dd id="formula1">
  <div id="lewishamilton">

    <p>Lewis Hamilton</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>  

  <div id="michaelschumacher">

    <p>Michael Schumacher</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

**jQuery:**

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    var allLinks = $('a.heading');
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        allLinks.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });

    var hash = 'michaelschumacher';
    if (hash) {
        var el = $('#' + hash);
        el.parent().slideDown();
        el.parent().prev().find('a').addClass('active');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Because jsfiddle puts the page inside a frame that has a different URL. http://fiddle.jshell.net/7k9s1pg7/7/show/light/#michaelschumacher

Comment: @Juhana Thanks for this. It works locally, but unfortuantely doesn't work on my WordPress install. I've no idea why :'-(

Comment: Well then show us the actual problem on your live system …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this before the closing  element resolved my issue.

Really odd how it worked locally but not on WordPress locally - using the exact same code :-O

```
<script>
    if (location.hash) {
        location.href = location.hash;
    }
</script>
```